# gravity rising, no airlock activity

Tags: mead, specific-gravity, honey, gravity-reading

fermenting a bochet, I dropped a bluetooth hydrometer in the must and started with a gravity reading of 1.128. Pitched lalvin EC-1118, and over a day the gravity has gone *up* to 1.144. I've heard that if your yeast is active enough, it can physically push your hydrometer up, and throw your reading off. However, would that not mean that I should have some visible airlock activity?

I'm also quite sure my airlock is working properly - the fermenter is a corny keg, so when I pull the pressure valve on the lid I can see the fluid level in the airlock drop. If I remove the airlock and push it on again, I can see it start at a higher level, and pull the pressure valve, I can watch it again.

what could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, gravity can't go up...so it sounds like the honey probably wasn't dispersed evenly in the water. I imagine getting caramelized honey to evenly disperse probably takes aeration or an immersion blender. If you just dumped thick honey and water in a keg and gave it a shake- it probably had pockets where the honey was more dense than others and threw off your reading.

For the airlock...it sounds like it's working- isn't it? Why would the airlock move when you pull the release tab if there was no positive pressure in the keg? That said..it's only been a single day so you'll probably need to wait another day (Although at this time..it's been a few days). As an aside I would really recommend adding some yeast nutrient if you haven't already.

Comment: unevenly dispersed honey sounds like the best idea. I'll tell you what I did; I boiled the honey in a brew kettle, and when the boil was done I slowly added water, and stirred to mix. I transferred this must to primary through the tap. I have been feeding it, and it looks like the gravity gradually went up and is now coming back down. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯